# Reading order of H.P.Lovecraft's stories

Tags: suggested-order, h-p-lovecraft

I want to start reading some H.P.Lovecraft stories since I've heard a lot of good things about them. Now from what I've gathered, they all take place in our world and some have recurring characters (I believe the mythos of Cthulhu and Dagon are covered in different books starring the same character).

That's why I was wondering, is there a reading order for his stories or could I just pick up any one of his books and start reading ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not a duplicate question - it's asking about the best order to read HPL's stories, not his novels.  However, the answer to the question about his novels points out that there are only three stories which might be described as novels, discusses them, then goes on to discuss/recommend several of the better stories.   So it's a good answer to this question, even though the previous question is more restricted.

Answer (score 0):

All of H.P.'s stories are pretty self-contained. There really isn't any canonical storyline. H.P. was writing for the pulp magazines, and wasn't (in his own estimation) writing great literature, so he didn't bother with keeping any continuity.

His greatest strength was in his imagination and mastery of the *almost*-seen. His worst fault was his occasional very ugly racism. (not unusual for his time, but he wasn't helping). But don't expect continuity.